# Existence of a function with $||grad f||>\epsilon$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, gradient-flows

I want to construct a function $f$ on the unit ball $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that it is negative on a closed subset of the boundary $\partial'B\subsetneqq\partial B$, zero on a given point $p\in B$, and there exists an $\epsilon >0$ such that $||grad f||>\epsilon$

My aproach was this. I take an open neighborhood $U\subset \partial B$ of a point on the boundary such that $\bar{U}\cap\partial'B=\emptyset$.

I can find an appropriate affine function $f$ such that it is positive on $U$ and negative on $\partial B\backslash U$. This function also has constant positive $||grad f||$. The problem is, it might not be zero at the given point.

To fix this I tried to move the inside of $B$ while keeping the boundary invariant. I can do this if I take the flow $\Phi$ of a vector field on $B$, which vanishes on the boundary. Then $f\circ\Phi$ has the same boundary behaviour as $f$, and is zero at $p$. My concern is, it might not longer have $||grad (f\circ\Phi)||>\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$

Please let me know if it can be proved that this function's gradient has the wanted property, or if there's a different approach that works. Thank you

Comment: you will have to let $f$ take positive values on the boundary. Consider the integral curve $\gamma$ of $grad f$ starting at $p$. Then $f\circ\gamma$ has first derivative $(f\circ\gamma)'=df(gradf)=||grad f||^2>\epsilon^2$

Comment: And since $f(p)=(f\circ\gamma)(0)=0$, for $t>0$ it is $(f\circ\gamma)(t)>0$

Comment: ah but the closed subset is not fixed, is it?

Comment: It is, you don't get to decide what it is. Otherwise, it is not difficult

Comment: There's not a lot of options in 1 dimension. It has to be negative on at least one point and it cannot be negative on both points or it will have a minimum (and hence zero gradient). So any carefully chosen affine function will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote the closed set by K, and fix a point $q\in \partial B\backslash K$. You can diffeomorphically map $B \backslash q$ to upper-half $R_n$ by $\Phi$. Denote the coordinates on $R_n$ by $y^i$, for $i=1,...,n$. Now $\Phi(K)$ is on $\{y^n=0\}$. Denote the $y^n$ coordinate of $\Phi(p)$ by $\psi^n$. Then $h=−exp(−y^n)+exp(-\psi^n)$ is negative on $\Phi(K)$ and equals to zero at $\Phi(p)$.

The function $h(\Phi)$ almost satisfy your condition, it is smooth and has non-vanishing gradient on $\overline B\backslash q$, and negative on K, and equals to zero at $p$. However it's singular at $q$. Then we can do a small perturbation to eliminate the singularity.